# Tried making a bar plot but came out as a stacked bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

> ```
> mean.CTR <- aggregate(CTR ~ Objective...1,adv,mean)
> barplot(mean.CTR)
> mean.CTR %>% as.data.frame()
> CTR.object<-data.frame(
> group = c("BRAND_AWARENESS", "CONVERSIONS ", "LINK_CLICKS ","POST_ENGAGEMENT","PRODUCT_CATALOG_SALES","REACH"),
> value = c(0.243, 1.48 , 1.77, 0.409,3.27,0.128)
> )
> ggplot(CTR.object, aes(x="", y=value, fill=group))+
> geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")`
> ```

I used the above code to make the bar plot however the bar plot came out as a stacked bar [image]

I trying to have my attributes on X axis

Comment: I have removed the conflicting RDBMS tags here. If the (R)DBMS is relevant, please [edit] your question to retag the appropriate one.

Comment: Why is your attempt in a block quote? Is it copied from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

For the x-axis use `group` and in `geom_bar()` use `position=position_dodge()`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(CTR.object, aes(x=group, y=value, fill=group))+ 
  geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity")+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0))
```

[image]